# Does the behavior of half-wave plate change with changes in the wavelength?

Tags: optics, waves

If we have a [half-wave plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate#Half-wave_plate) of fixed thickness, what will happen if the wavelength becomes twice as long?

Comment: The wavelength of what ? Usually, for a wave, when the wavelength $\lambda$ double, the frequency $\nu$ divides by two, providing the velocity $c$ of propagation of the wave in a medium reads $c=\lambda\nu$. Is that what you want as an answer ? Dos it make any sense to you ?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, anything can happen, because the refractive index of materials tends to be a function of the wavelength, and its dependence can be quite complex. Thus, it's perfectly possible for a material to be birefringent at some wavelength $\lambda$ and completely nondispersive at wavelength $2\lambda$.

---

However, it's worth asking what happens if the plate's refractive index stays relatively flat over some interval that spans from $\lambda_0$ to $2\lambda_0$. Generally speaking, the effect of a plate of birefringent material is to introduce a phase shift
$$
e^{i\varphi} = e^{2\pi i\, \Delta n\, L/\lambda}
$$
between the light polarized along the fast and slow axes of the crystal, where $L$ is the thickness of the plate (which is fixed) and $\Delta n$ the refractive-index difference between the two axes. Saying that the plate is a half-wave plate at a wavelength $\lambda_0$ means that it has been cut to a thickness of 
$$
L = \frac12\frac{\lambda_0}{\Delta n},
$$
so that the relative phase between the fast and the slow axes is $e^{i\varphi}=e^{i\pi}=-1$ for light at $\lambda_0$. If that waveplate's retartance is flat with respect to the wavelength, though, then at $\lambda=2\lambda_0$ it will imprint a phase
$$
e^{i\varphi} = e^{2\pi\pi i\, \Delta n\, L/2\lambda_0} = e^{i\pi/2} = i,
$$
i.e., it will act as a quarter-wave plate. At wavelengths in between, it will switch linearly between half-wave plate and quarter-wave plate, so that it will produce elliptically polarized light from any linear polarization that doesn't match either of the two special axes.

For a broadband light source, of course, this can be very inconvenient, because if you want a waveplate you normally want its action to be the same for all the wavelengths you're using. Fortunately, though, this is possible with achromatic waveplates like e.g. [these ones](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2193), which are made from materials whose retardance $\Delta n$ increases linearly with the wavelength, so that the relationship $L= \frac12 \frac{\lambda}{\Delta n(\lambda)}$ can be maintained, at least approximately, over some nontrivial range.